# How to use Tor Expert Bundle on Windows?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

A step by step guide would be awesome on how to use it and  how to configure normal Mozilla Firefox to use proxy to reroute all traffic through Tor using Expert Bundle. (no Vidalia Solution)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using normal Firefox with a Tor proxy? Anonymity, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Download and run tor.exe. Open Mozilla Firefox and under network settings, configure proxy and port as 127.0.0.1 and 9050 respectively. But it is recommended to use TBB to remain completely anonymous